# How to fix RadGridView paging right to left?

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid

See RadGridView image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A4IW.png)

when i try to make it right to left:

```
this.radGridView1.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vpTh.png)

GridView is now right to left but paging section is still left to right only changing arrows.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First you should set `AllowCustomPaging` to `True`, additionally you can include
`<PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages" />` or
`<PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages" PagerTextFormat="{4} Page {0} from {1}, rows {2} to {3} from {5}" />`.

But I strongly suggest you look into this: [Telerik Custom Paging Documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/functionality/paging/changing-the-default-pager/using-pagertextformat)